# Trouble understanding simple C statement

Tags: c

I have come across this macro:

```
#define PUT(p, val)  (*(int *)(p) = (val))
```

And I am not sure exactly how to translate it into a function. I think it means that p, once a pointer, dereferenced (so that you have an actually int p variable) is set equal to val. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky since it essentially does something you're not supposed to do (since it might cause undefined behavior).

A first step would be translating the macro into a function body:

```
? PUT(? p, ? val)  {
    return *(int *)(p) = (val);
}
```

There's some return value simply due to the fact that an assignment always returns its value. What about the data types? We'll come to that now:

The right side of the assignment is trivial, since there's really just the pair of brackets to avoid the macro param to somehow screw with the order of operands, so it's really just `val`.

The left side is a bit more complicated:

```
*(int *)(p)
```

Once again, the brackets around `p` just keep the order of operands, so it could now be simplified to this:

```
*(int *)p
```

This is evaluated from right to left:

- Take the value of `p`.
- Cast it to `int *`.
- Dereference it (`*`).

So the input is cast to an integer pointer. For this to be valid (and not completely nuts in some way), the input has to be a pointer as well. The easiest way to do this (and to allow any type similar to the macro), is to use `void*`.

Since you're assigning a value to an integer variable (and you return this value), the return type is going to be `int`.

With this said, you'll end up with something like this:

```
int PUT(void *p, int val) {
    return *(int *)(p) = (val);
}
```

Now, if you'd like to be extra specific, you could mark the function as `inline` so the code is actually inlined/pasted instead of called, but this is really up to the compiler:

```
inline int PUT(void *p, int val) {
    return *(int *)(p) = (val);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can break it down to make it easier to digest:

```
int *temp = (int *)p;
*temp = val;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to reinterpret `p` as an int pointer and write the result of the `(val)` expression wherever it points to. Shorter: write the int `val` at the address p.